# Magento 2 - Make log file accessible from browser

Tags: magento2, log, file-permissions, chrome-browser, browser

I created a custom log file like this:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/my_oh_my.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('TikTok');
```

How to make this log file can be accessed from the browser?

For example:

> http://base_url.com/var/log/my_oh_my.log

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want do this the easiest solution is to create a different folder inside the `pub/` folder. Lets say `pub/log/`. Then adjust your logging writer path to reflect that.

Other solutions are symlinking to the log file as well. I would not expose the `var/log` folder to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

This module can help you download via browser and secure - https://github.com/metasyncSite/Magento-2-log-viewer